# accessing files on mac os server via iOS app

Tags: ios, osx-lion

I'm writing an app, that needs secure storage. I have a mac OS lion server, and wondered how easy it would be to write the data to a folder on the server. In order to access a file/folder on the server from my laptop I hit CMD + k e.t.c and a popup appears requesting a username and password. The question is, is it possible to embed a username and password in the app so that it can access this file and if so how?

Comment: Of course the answer is yes - you can do this but its probably not wise, since someone can get your app, jailbreak their phone, then find the name/password within your app. Normal apps have the user enter such information. You may be able to use a certificate or something for security but this is beyond my knowledge. What you want to do is quite possible, you just need to do it in a secure fashion - and that will take some research on your part.

Comment: Thanks @DavidH I completely agree with what your saying. This app will not be distributed however, so the security issue isn't a problem. What I don't know how to do is get access to a file that needs a username and password?

Comment: My company set something up on our server to use a self signed certificate. I know nothing about this but was able to use the certificate to get through the security blocks - I would suggest going down this road rather than a name/password.